# How can I delay UINavigationController transitions in UIKit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, uikit

**The Situation:**
I have two view controllers (UIViewController) managed by a navigation controller (UINavigationController). On load, the first view controller, a sort of waiting screen, initiates loading of the second view controller, which takes some time. As it is now, the first view controller does not transition to the second view controller until all data has loaded -- which as I understand it is normal behavior in UIKit.

**The Problem:**
I want the first view controller (wait screen) to be displayed for AT LEAST 2 seconds while it waits for the second view controller to load. The problem is, sometimes the loading of the second view controller finishes before 2 seconds, and the 2 second wait is interrupted.

**The Dream:**
I want the transition from the first to the second view controller to DELAY until 2 seconds have elapsed.

**A) Dream Scenario A:** 
If the loading of the second view controller being pushed finishes before the 2 second delay, I want the transition (the animation you actually see) to be deferred until the 2 second delay has been fulfilled.

**B) Dream Scenario B:** 
If 2 seconds elapse BEFORE loading has finished the transition (the animation you actually see) should happen normally as soon as the loading is done.

Are there any callbacks or notifications in objective-c or cocoa that can allow me to do this?

Thanks.

**Update/Clarifications:** (*Sorry, was not as clear as I could've been*)
At first glance it may seem that NSTimer might be my solution. Well, unfortunately it is not. **I Know how to use NSTimer** to push the view controller after a delay (not the problem). I actually push the second view controller immediately when the first view controller loads. The idea being that, since the LOADING of the second view controller being pushed takes a while, I give the user a nice waiting screen with the first view controller.

**Reason for wanting control**:
There may be cases in which the loading of the second view controller being pushed finishes quickly -- in which case the first view controller may only be visible for a fraction of a second. This looks unprofessional. So instead of this, I want to show the waiting screen for a constant amount of time for consistency and to give some brief useful info about the app. My app is a book, and the waiting screen is more like a Frontis piece -- showing Title and Author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a method call in the future, I find the most convenient method to use is to use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

> performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:
>   Invokes a method of the receiver on
>   the current thread using the default
>   mode after a delay.
>
> - (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument
>     afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
>
> Parameters aSelector A selector that
>   identifies the method to invoke. The
>   method should not have a significant
>   return value and should take a single
>   argument of type id, or no arguments.
>   See “Selectors” for a description of
>   the SEL type. anArgument The argument
>   to pass to the method when it is
>   invoked. Pass nil if the method does
>   not take an argument. delay The
>   minimum time before which the message
>   is sent. Specifying a delay of 0 does
>   not necessarily cause the selector to
>   be performed immediately. The selector
>   is still queued on the thread’s run
>   loop and performed as soon as
>   possible. Discussion This method sets
>   up a timer to perform the aSelector
>   message on the current thread’s run
>   loop. The timer is configured to run
>   in the default mode
>   (NSDefaultRunLoopMode). When the timer
>   fires, the thread attempts to dequeue
>   the message from the run loop and
>   perform the selector. It succeeds if
>   the run loop is running and in the
>   default mode; otherwise, the timer
>   waits until the run loop is in the
>   default mode.

Answer (score 2):

**First way** works if there is no multithreading issues:

```
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
```

Choosing **second way** is supposed you to implement some simple selector `pushSomeViewControllerSelector` where the transition takes place:

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(pushSomeViewControllerSelector)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
```